# Evaluating two limits related to prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, limits, analytic-number-theory

How to find these limits
 $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\ln(\ln(n)) - \sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k \ln(k)}\right)$ ?

and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \ln(\ln(n)) - \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{p_k}\right)$?

where $p_k$ is the $k$'th prime number.

Comment: slightly related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79115/limit-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-left2-sqrt-n-sum-limits-k-1n-frac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second limit is precisely [Mertens Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensConstant.html).

The constant of the first limit, lets call it $C_{-1}$.  I am not sure if it has a name.  I believe Ramanujan computed that it was approximately $\approx 0.7946786$.   [See page 11 of this PDF for more details](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0706/0706.0343v2.pdf).

Remarkably it also appears in the following limit due to Ramanujan:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)}-\log n=C_{-1}.$$

Comment: In Mertens' constant, the sum is over the primes not exceeding $n$. In the current question, the sum is over the first $n$ primes (if we have figured out what OP wanted to say). It is not clear to me that the two different sums yield the same constant.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I didn't see that, but it is still the same constant.  Since $p_k\sim k\log k$ we are looking at $$\log\log \left(k\log k+o(k\log k)\right)+B_1+o(1).$$  If we carefully work the error through the logarithms, it remains $$\log \log k+B_1+o(1).$$

Comment: For the 1st limit, the author just gives that number, and a citation of a paper of Boas. But Boas gives the constant as .42816572, so I don't know where the author gets .7946786.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I am pretty sure that 0.7946786 is correct.  I computed it numerically, and then googled the number I found.  That is how I found the references to Ramanujans Notebooks in the first place, and the other paper.  I am not sure if google books links work, but try:  http://books.google.ca/books?id=liTRR8UnTq4C&pg=PA166&lpg=PA166&dq=0.7946786&source=bl&ots=mbTIgrkyRL&sig=TBkzDvLKJLUEGq8xeszGPfBPano&hl=en&ei=4UK3TuOrLcnN4QTPtN3zAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=0.7946786&f=false

Comment: I think what I missed is that Boas is talking about $\int_2^n(dx/x\log x)$ while we're talking about $\log\log n$, and they differ by $\log\log2$.

Answer (score 1):

Mertens proved the existence of $$\lim(\sum_{p\le n}(1/p)-\log\log n)$$ see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems) for more detail, or any good textbook for a proof. This isn't quite what's wanted in the second problem above, but it should get you started.