# Elementary proof of an estimate on $\zeta$

Tags: asymptotics, riemann-zeta

I saw somewhere that

> If $s=\sigma +it$ where $\sigma >0$ and $t\in \mathbb R$,$x\geq |t|/\pi\implies \zeta(s)=\displaystyle \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{x^{1-s}}{s-1}+O(x^{-\sigma})$

- What's the meaning of the asymptotics here ? I don't understand which variables are fixed and which are free.
- Is there a way to prove this with undergraduate means when $t=0$ ?

Comment: I prove a slightly weaker version of that (without the specific $O(x^{-\sigma})$ bound on the error term) using complex analysis [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/729787/5531).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof (for $t=0$ and $s\neq 1$) is given by Euler's summation formula, see Theorem $3.2$ in the book "Introduction to Analytic Number Theory" by Tom Apostol. We just need $x\ge 1$; the asymptotics refers to $x\mapsto \infty$.