# Proving Asymptotic Barrier - O notation for $\ln(n!)$

Tags: asymptotics

I'm interested in the exact barrier of $$\ln(n!)= \Theta(n\ln(n))$$

and if it even exists.

This means, there is a $c_1, c_2$ , so that $$\ln(n!) \le  \Theta(n\ln(n) c_1$$ 
$$\ln(n!) \ge  \Theta(n\ln(n) c_2$$

or

$$0 \le \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(n!)}{n\ln(n)} \ge \infty$$

I could use de l'Hospital for the limit fraction, since it's $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ but the derivate of $\ln(n!)$ causes problems. Also I don't know how I could prove the two statements above or how to prove them wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I assume that by "asymptotic barrier," you mean asymptotic equivalent? (i.e., tight characterization of the form $\ln n! = (1+o(1))f(n)$)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean. 
The question is if there is a c1 and c2 , so that one of my functions limits the other for the whole rest of the function. Here I have a [link](http://www.igi.tugraz.at/lehre/D&A/WS10/Hilfsblaetter/Asymptotische_Schranken.pdf) where you might recognize on the graphics what I'm unable to communicate. Page two, bottom half.

Comment: @Ian That is an asymptotic equivalent" $\ln(n!) = (1+o(1)) n\ln n$.

Comment: @ClementC. Derp, sorry, forgot that it's multiplicative, not additive.

Comment: (From the rest of the question, it looks like the OP actually want a looser analysis -- a $\Theta(n\ln n)$ would suffice.)

Comment: In that case, you have $n \ln(n) (1-1/\ln(n)) \leq \ln(n!) \leq n \ln(n)$, at least for sufficiently large $n$. This follows because the first two terms of the asymptotic expansion are $n \ln(n)-n$ and the next term is positive. In this case I think the "sufficiently large $n$" can actually be dropped (i.e. the inequality holds for $n \geq 1$). So you can take $c_2=1/2,c_1=1$ once $n \geq 8$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488194/giving-an-asymptotically-tight-bound-on-sum-sum-k-1n-log-2-k2/1488203), I give two answers below -- the first one is simple, and applies if you do not care about getting the *exact constant* in the asymptotic (i.e., if a $\Theta(\cdot)$ result is enough). The second is a tad longer, but gives the exact leading term; and actually more (i.e., it will also yield the two or three next low-order terms, in this particular case).

---

**Method 1:** Upper and lower bounds.
Note that $\ln(n!) = \sum_{k=1}^n \ln k$. You have 
$$
\sum_{k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor }^n \ln k \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \ln k \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \ln n = n \ln n
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor }^n \ln k \geq \frac{n}{2}\ln \left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor \geq \frac{n}{2}\ln\left(\frac{n}{2} - 1\right) = \frac{n}{2}\left(\ln(n-2) - \ln 2\right) \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty}  \frac{1}{2} n\ln n.
$$
Putting it together, 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \ln k = \Theta\left( n \ln n \right)
$$
and moreover you have, for any $\epsilon\in(0,1]$ and $n$ big enough,
$$\frac{1-\epsilon}{2}n\ln n \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \ln k \leq n\ln n.$$

---

**Method 2:** Using integrals, often much easier to handle than sums.

Note that $\ln(n!) = \sum_{k=1}^n \ln k$. We will use the fact that $f=\ln$ is a non-decreasing function on $[1,\infty)$ to do a comparison series-integral. (I am using $f$ afterwards to highlight that this is a general technique)

For any $k$, we have that 
$$
f(k) \leq f(x) \leq f(k+1)
$$
for all $x\in[k,k+1)$. Integrating the inequality on $[k,k+1)$, we get
$$
f(k) = \int_k^{k+1} f(k) dx \leq \int_k^{k+1} f(x) dx \leq \int_k^{k+1} f(k+1) dx = f(k+1).
$$
Summing this inequality for $k$ between $1$ and $n-1$, we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f(k) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_k^{k+1} f(x) dx = \int_1^{n} f(x) dx \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f(k+1) = \sum_{k=2}^{n} f(k)
$$
or, rearranging (and adding the missing terms $f(1)$ and $f(n)$ when needed to complete the sum),
$$
\int_1^{n} f(x) dx  + f(1) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k) \leq \int_1^{n} f(x) dx + f(n).
$$
Now, we want to use the squeeze theorem, so that *this will only work if $f(n)$ and $f(1)$ are negligible in front of $\int_1^{n} f(x) dx$* (otherwise, the "squeezing" cannot happen). Fortunately, this is the case here.

More precisely, you have
$$
\int_1^{n} f(x) dx = \int_1^{n} \ln x dx = \left[x\ln x -x\right]^n_1 = n\ln n - n + 1
$$
and $f(1)=0$, $f(n)=\ln n$. Therefore, you have
$$
n\ln n - n + 1 \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln k \leq n\ln n - n + \ln n +  1
$$
that is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln k = n\ln n - n + o(n).
$$
If you are only interested in the leading term:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln k \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} n\ln n.
$$

(also, by any means -- please, why L'Hospital?)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, that helps a lot! Indeed I meant a looser analysis, I'm sorry I had no clue how to call that in English.

Comment: This is a nice development!  +1.  Another way forward within Method $1$ is to note that $(2n)!\ge n^n$.  Then, we see that $\log((2n)!)\ge n\log(n)$.  And we have for the other side, $(2n)!\le (2n)^{2n}$ from which we find $\log((2n)!) \le 2n\log(2n)$.