# Convergency of series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The task is to prove, that series: 
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{log^2(n!)}$$
converges.
Unfortunately I only managed to deal with showing that Limit of the summand is equal to 0, what is pretty obvious, but still, I am truly clueless, how to show that it converges. I am not asking for solution, but only clues/hints and other stuff like that. I would be truly grateful for any help.

Comment: Are you familiar with Stirling's formula?

Comment: Unfortunetly...no.

Comment: Note that eventually $n!>e^n$ .

Comment: Show that for $n\geq 4$, you have $n!\geq 2^n$.

Comment: @Aitor Ormazabal It's not like that to prove that one series converges by comparison test, the "bigger" one should converge, not the smaller one?

Comment: Use $n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$ And substitute into the log. argument, then use log properties for products...

Comment: @Henry: I suspect that  Aitor Ormazabal and Kelenner and Thomas's observations are a simpler approach, depending on the base of the loagrithm

Comment: Yes, but taking reciprocals reverses the inequality: If you can prove that $log^2(n!)>n^2$ then you have $\dfrac {1}{log^2(n!)}<\dfrac {1}{n^2}$ and you can use comparison

Comment: My mistake, sorry. Also great idea. Thanks!

Comment: That series cannot converge. Series starts from $n = 1$ which is a pole for the $\log$ functions. First term diverges yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** [you can easily show](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1489796/75808) that $\ln(n!) \geq c n\ln n$ for some absolute constant $c >0$. From there, $\frac{1}{\ln^2 n!} \leq \frac{1}{c^2 n^2\ln^2 n}$, and conclude by theorems of comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the comments above, you first note that $n! > e^n$ for $n\geq k$ (for some $k$). Then you can say that for $n\geq k$
$$
\log(n!)^2 > (\log(e^n))^2  = (n\log(e))^2 = n^2.
$$
So
$$
\frac{1}{\log(n!)^2} < \frac{1}{n^2}.
$$
Then you can use the comparison test.

Comment: By $log(x)$ I mean $log_e(x)$

Comment: @Kiwi: Ok,  will update.

Comment: The series cannot converge, it starts from $n = 1$: first terms diverges yet!

Answer (score 1):

By summation by parts, for any $n\geq 3$:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\log(n!) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(k) &=& n\log(n) - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\\&\geq& n\log n-\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot\frac{1}{k}\\&=&n\left(\log n-1\right)\tag{1}\end{eqnarray*} $$
since $\log(1+x)\leq x$ for any $x>0$. The $p$-test hence ensures that $\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{\log^2(n!)}$ is converging, but the sum has to avoid the $n=1$ term since $\log(1!)=0$.