# How can I solve this Big $O$ exercise?

Tags: computational-complexity

How can I prove that  $n \log_2(n) ∈ O(log(n!))$  is true?

We start by supposing that $f(n)< c g(n)$ is true,

which means that $n \log_2(n) > c \log(n!)$ for all $n>n_0$ and $c>0$.

Comment: Not that it matters, but in $\log(n!)$, what is the base?  And you will end up wanting to show that $n\log_2(n)$ is **less than** $c\log(n!)$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: There are a lot of related questions, but you could first start with the usual trick: $\log(n!) = \log \prod_{j=1}^n j = \sum_{j=1}^n \log j > \sum_{j=n/2}^n \log j > \sum_{j=n/2}^n \log \frac{n}{2} > \dots$...

Comment: Related: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489770/proving-asymptotic-barrier-o-notation?lq=1 and linked posts therein.

Comment: They don't specify a base for log (n!).. I suppose it is not important when calculating the big O

Comment: Could you please explain me why do you make the transition from 
 ∑ j=n/2 to n (log j) >∑ j=n/2 to n (log n/2) ?

Comment: Regarding my comment above: $\sum_{j=1}^n \log j > \sum_{j=n/2}^n \log j$ because each term in the sum is positive, and the LHS has more terms than the RHS.  Then $ \sum_{j=n/2}^n \log j > \sum_{j=n/2}^n \log \frac{n}{2}  $ because $\log j > \log \frac{n}{2}$ for all $j>\frac{n}{2}$, since $\log$ is increasing.