# Does $\sum _{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\ln\left(n!\right)}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I spend too much time on this one,and I just can't find a way to prove anything. Please, will someone help me?

> Does $$ \sum _{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\ln\left(n!\right)}$$ converge?

P.S. Does anybody knows where can I find (online) these kind of tasks (I mean, with this kind of difficulty). Thank you (in advance). :)

Comment: Well, you don't want to start at n=1 I would assume

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**, it does not.

[It is standard to see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489770/proving-asymptotic-barrier-o-notation/1489796#1489796) that $\ln n! \sim_{n\to\infty} n\ln n$, so that the series with positive terms $\sum_n \frac{1}{\ln n!}$ and $\sum_n \frac{1}{n \ln n}$ have same nature by theorems of comparison.

But the latter diverges, as a Bertrand series.$^{(\dagger)}$

---

> **Theorem.** *(Bertrand series)* The series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^a(\ln n)^b}$  converges if, and only if, **(i)** $a>1$ or **(ii)** $a=1$ and $b>1$.

Comment: Standard with or without Stirling ?

Comment: Might want to reference [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) .

Comment: @AlexisOlson See the link provided. No need for Stirling, actually.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM without: Look at $(\sum_{k=1}^n \ln k)/(n\ln n)$ with Stolz-Cesaro.

Comment: @zhw the integral method he referenced is even more elementary

Comment: Without invoking Bertrand series, one can also show that $\sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{n\ln n}$ diverges by (yet another) integral comparison, since $\int_2^N \frac{dx}{x\ln x} = \ln\ln N - \ln\ln 2$.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Disagree, SC is simpler (if you know it) (IMO of course)

Comment: @zhw. The comments are not really the place for a debate on "what is simpler, and what does 'simple' mean in terms of a tradeoff between conciseness of the proof and level of the tools used in it." As for the question itself, all that is needed is that $\ln n! \leq n\ln n$, which is actually immediate since $\ln n! = \sum_{k=1}^n \ln k \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \ln n$.

Comment: @ClementC. Actually, zhw was responding to a question posted by LeGrandDODOM.  It was the latter who began the debate of which method was simpler.  ;-))

Comment: Fait enough :) @Dr.MV

Comment: And +1 for the solution

Answer (score 4):

For all $n >1$, we have $n^n > n!$.  Therefore, $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n^n} < \frac{1}{n!}$, and further $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\ln(n^n)} < \frac{1}{\ln(n!)}$ since $\ln(x)$ is an increasing function.  By a property of logarithms, we have $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\ln(n^n)} = \frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$.

Since $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n \ln(n)}$ can be shown to diverge with, e.g., the integral test, it follows that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\ln(n!)}$ diverges per the comparison test.