# How to find limit of the sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{1\leq i<j\le n}\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{ij}}$?

Tags: limits, analysis

> Find limit of the sequence$$a_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{1\leq i<j\le n}\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{ij}}.$$

I have no idea how to solve it.
I don't know where to start.

Comment: your question is not clear, retype your problem in the question text space and not just on the title

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): *Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true (you may genuinely have no idea how to approach the problem), it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.*

Comment: Hint: use [$\lim_{j\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt j}\sum_{i=1}^j\frac{1}{\sqrt i}=2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170393/convergence-of-a-n-frac1-sqrtn-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1-sqrtk?noredirect=1) plus [Cesaro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#Arithmetic_mean).

Comment: can you please provide one more hint. I don't know how to use this limit in $a_n$

Answer (score 2):

The sequence
$$b_j:=\frac1{\sqrt j}\sum_{1\le i<j}\frac1{\sqrt i}$$ [converges to $2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170393), hence [so does its Cesàro mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#Arithmetic_mean)
$$a_n=\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^nb_j.$$