# What is the rate of growth of the sum of reciprocals of square roots of natural numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We all know that $$ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \sim \log(n).$$

What is the analagous result for $\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-1/2}$ ?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: It should be $O(\sqrt{n})$, but deriving the leading order behavior and possibly the next order is more interesting.

Comment: I have now edited the post.

Comment: You can bound $\sum_k f(k)$ by $\int_{k=?}^\infty f(k) dk$, as long as $f(.)$ is non-increasing/non-decreasing. The key is to interpret it as a Riemann sum of $f(k)$.

Comment: The complete asymptotic expansion can be found at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79115/limit-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-left2-sqrt-n-sum-limits-k-1n-frac).

Comment: I changed \textrm{~}\hspace{3mm} to \sim, and log(n) to \log(n).  The  takes care of the spacing, makes the tilde match the font, and prevents italicization of $\log$.  It's standard usage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By looking at upper and lower Riemann sums on this decreasing function, you can bracket it by $$\int_1^{n} x^{-\frac 12}\ dx \lt \sum_{k=1}^nk^{-\frac 12} \lt \int_0^{n-1} x^{-\frac 12}\ dx\\2\sqrt n-2\lt \sum_{k=1}^nk^{-\frac 12} \lt2\sqrt {n-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac \beta{k^\alpha} - \frac \beta{(k+1)^\alpha} \sim \frac {\alpha\beta}{k^{\alpha +  1}} = \frac 1{\sqrt{k}}
$$if $\alpha = -1/2$ and $\beta = -2$

now as $\sum \frac 1{\sqrt{k}} = \infty$:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^N \frac 1{\sqrt{k}}\sim \sum_{k=1}^N \frac \beta{k^\alpha} - \frac \beta{(k+1)^\alpha}
\sim -\frac \beta{N^\alpha} = 2\sqrt{N}
$$