# Is there an easy way to find exact value of $\left\lfloor{H_{10^6}^\left({\frac12}\right)}\right\rfloor$ without using a calculator

Tags: harmonic-numbers

Is there an easy way to calculate $f(x)=\left\lfloor{H_{x}^\left({\frac12}\right)}\right\rfloor$ for large $x\in\mathbb{N}$ where
$${H_{x}^\left({\frac12}\right)}=\sum_{n=1}^xn^{-\frac12}$$
without using a calculator? For example, how to calculate $f\left({10^6}\right)$? It is known that derivative of ${H_{x}^\left({\frac12}\right)}$ is monotonically decreasing for all real positive numbers and $f(x)<2000$ for all $0<x<10^6$. I computed $f\left({10^6}\right)$ using Mathematica and it is equal to $1998$, but is it possible to find it without using programs or calculators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/670202/59379), the sum has
an asymptotic expansion of the form
$$\sum_{n=1}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \approx 
2\sqrt{x} 
+ \zeta(1/2) 
+ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}
-\frac{1}{24}{x}^{-3/2}+{\frac {1}{384}}\,{x}^{-7/2} + \cdots$$
If you want a quick answer for large $x$, you just keep the first two term in the
expansion and get $$f\left(10^6\right) \approx \left\lfloor 2\sqrt{10^6} -1.460354508809587 \right\rfloor = 1998$$

Comment: Can we prove that $-2<\zeta\left({\frac12}\right)<-1$ without using a calculator?

Comment: @Mathematician171 If you just want a bound, you can compare the sum to corresponding integral. Since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is monotonic decreasing, we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{x-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} > \int_1^x \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}} >\sum_{n=2}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
\implies 2\sqrt{x} - 2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < \sum_{n=1}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < 2\sqrt{x}-1
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
If we use the *Abel-Plana Formula* and neglects the contribution from the integral
$\ds{\pars{~\mbox{the one which involves the factor}\
     \bracks{\expo{2\pi z} - 1}^{-1}~}}$ we find:
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{x}{1 \over \root{n}}}
=\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over \root{n + 1}} - {1 \over \root{n + x + 1}}}
\\[5mm]&\approx\int_{0}^{\infty}
\pars{{1 \over \root{z + 1}} - {1 \over \root{z + x + 1}}}\,\dd z
+ \half\left.\pars{{1 \over \root{n + 1}} - {1 \over \root{n + x + 1}}}
\right\vert_{n\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large2\pars{\root{x + 1} - 1}
+\half\pars{1 - {1 \over \root{x + 1}}}}
\end{align}

---

With $\ds{\color{#66f}{\large x = 10^{6}}}$ we got:
$$
\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{x}{1 \over \root{n}}}
\approx {4000003 \over 2\root{1000001}} - {3 \over 2}
\approx \color{#66f}{\large 1998.5005}
$$