# Beginner's question：The question that arises when doing a simple sequence convergence problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The sequence：$$
    x_n=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots \cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-2\sqrt{n}
    $$
My question：$$
x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}-2\sqrt{n+1}+2\sqrt{n}
=\frac{2\sqrt{n^2+n}-2n-1}{\sqrt{n+1}}<0
$$
So, the sequence is monotonically decreasing.
But,
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{i}{n}}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n}\int_0^1{x^{-\frac{1}{2}}}dx}}=\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}2\sqrt{n}
$$
Does that mean that the sum of the previous series is similar to $$
2\sqrt{n}
$$？
So I can think of the limit of this sequence as zero.
That's clearly not true given the monotonicity that i had before.

Comment: I sort of know that the sum is going to be different than I thought, but I'd like to hear suggestion.

Comment: Not clear to me what the question is. But to check convergence you might first try to get a feel by calculating a couple of terms, at least  $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$.

Comment: The right notation to use would be [asymptotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) ; i.e, $1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sim 2\sqrt{x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}2\sqrt{n}
$$

is useless because is the exact same as saying $\ \infty = \infty,\ $ which tells you nothing. You may as well have written:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}2^n\ (= +\infty)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that monotonicity for a sequence $a_n$ doesn't imply that the limit can't be equal to zero (or to any other value).

For example, $a_n = \frac 1 n$ is monotonically decreasing but $a_n \to 0$.

Refer also to the related:

- [Evaluate: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left({2\sqrt n}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt k}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/79115/505767)