# Tight Order of the Infinite Series $\sum_{k=1}^n1/\sqrt{k}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am studying mathematical analysis, and I wonder what is the order of the series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}.
$$
I am able to show that it is $O(\sqrt{n})$:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}}\le2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k-1}+\sqrt{k}}=2\sum_{k=1}^n(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1})=2\sqrt{n}.
$$
Is the order tight? That is, is it true that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=\Theta(\sqrt{n})?
$$

Comment: of course - use the integral test to bound the sum between the integral of $1/\sqrt x$ taken from $1$ to $n-1$ and $2$ to $n$ respectively

Comment: You are right. Alternatively, $\sum_{k=1}^n1/\sqrt{k}\ge\sum_{k=1}^n1/\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: In fact, it is easy to show, for example by comparing the area under the graph of $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lceil x\rceil}}$, that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}-\int_{0}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ is not only bounded but convergent as $n\to\infty$. (For the interested user, the limit turns out to be the value $\zeta(\frac{1}{2})$ of the Riemann zeta function.)

Comment: According to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/670202/59379), the sum has asymptotic expansion:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \asymp 
2\sqrt{n} 
+ \zeta\left(\frac12\right) 
+ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}
-\frac{1}{24}{n}^{-\frac32}+{\frac {1}{384}}\,{n}^{-\frac72} + \cdots$$

Comment: @Conrad  could you please tell me where "the integral test"  can be found in modern textbooks?  We learned precisely that, including endpoint shifts,  using simple diagrams; but I can't seem to find that exact statement.   The version I paste into answers is: If we have $g(x) > 0$ but $g'(x) < 0,$  then
$$ \int_a^{b+1} \; g(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=a}^b \;  g(j) \; < \; \int_{a-1}^b \;  g(x) \; dx   $$

Comment: @Will I don't know offhand where one finds an explicitly stated version but the integral test works when $g$ is integrable and monotonic, one doesn't need positivity or smoothness; if $g$ decreasing your formula above applies; if $g$ increasing the inequalities reverse since now $ \int_{k-1}^{k}g(x)dx \le g(k) \le \int_k^{k+1}g(x)dx$ - also we can adjust the endpoints as needed to get tighter inequalities if needed, while if we know more about $g$ (eg convexity) we can do even tighter bounds with half-integer intervals

Comment: @Conrad  thank you. I should have said that this was in high school, close to 50 years ago. I also like the part about using half integers.  The other direction, from a text file I keep handy  for Latex/Mathjax code: if we have $f(x) > 0$ and $f'(x) > 0,$  then
$$ \int_{a-1}^{b} \; f(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=a}^b \;  f(j) \; < \; \int_{a}^{b+1} \;  f(x) \; dx   $$