# Finding $f$ satisfying $\int f=\sum f$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

This question is related to [this other one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536/finding-f-such-that-int-f-sum-f), but this other question does not give the answer to this one.

> Find all function $f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R\in C^\infty(]0,+\infty[)$ such that $f'=0$ has at most one zero, and $$\int_0^1 f(x)\mathrm d x=\sum_{n\geqslant 1} f(n).$$

We can prove that $f(x)=\frac 1{x^x}$ will work:

- $f'(x)=-x^{-x}(1+\log x)$ has only one zero;
- using $$x^x=e^{x\log x}=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{(x\log x)^n}{n!}$$

and an inversion $\sum-\int$ (and the value of $\int_0^1 (x\log x)^n\mathrm d x$);

we can show that 
$$\int_0^1 \frac 1{x^x}\mathrm d x=\sum_{n\geqslant 1} \frac 1{n^n}.$$

---

Is there any other function $f$ satisfying those conditions?

Comment: Relevant keyword: [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream)

Comment: If $f$ is only defined on $(0, 1)$, what is $f(n)$  for $n\geq 1$?

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you for the link!

Comment: Your edit doesn't fix the problem. *Any* $f \in C^\infty(]0,1[)$ can be extended to all of $\Bbb R$ in such a way as to satisfy your conditions. In fact, they can be extended in infinitely many ways to do so. Finding all such $f$ is going to be a very wide collection of functions.

Comment: This question needs to be stated properly, or it should be closed.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I think it is better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are millions of them.

Take any function $g(x)$ such that $g'(x)e^x$ is monotonic* and such that the integral and the sum converge. Then let

$$f(x):=g(x)+ae^{-x}$$ and write

$$\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=\int_0^1 g(x)\,dx+a(1-e^{-1})=I+a(1-e^{-1}),$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n)+\frac{ae}{1-e^{-1}}=S+\frac{ae}{1-e^{-1}},$$ which you can solve for $a$ after equating.

---

*This requirement ensures a single root of $f'(x)$.

Comment: About the same, but maybe a little easier: $f(x) = e^{-ax}$ for a suitable $a>0$ will work. This one has $f'(x) < 0$ everywhere.

Comment: @zhw: in what way is it easier ? [And by the way, this $f$ works for a few $a$ only.]